# Definitions of Determinants and Permanents in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, definition, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

I have been recently reading a QFT book called: "QFT For the Gifted Amateur". It states in footnote 4 on p. 40 that the [determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) and [permanents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of matrices can be defined as follows:
$$ \det\left(A\right)=\sum_{P}^{ }\left(-1\right)^{P}\prod_{i=1}^{N}A_{iP\left(i\right)} $$
$$ \text{per}\left(A\right)=\sum_{P}^{ }\prod_{i=1}^{N}A_{iP\left(i\right)}. $$
It says in the book that:

> "There are $N!$ permutations of the sequence of integers $i = 1, . . . , N$ and $P(i)$ labels a permutation of this sequence."

I am very confused as to what is actually happening here (i.e.: what are the limits of summation, what is $P$ and how is it defined, etc.). Before this section, the book stated that for an $N$-particle state:
$$ |ψ_{1},…,ψ_{N}⟩=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}}\sum_{P}ξ^{P}\prod_{i=1}^{N}|ψ_{P(i)}⟩ \tag{4.19}$$
Where, ξ is equal to either positive or negative one (positive one corresponds to bosons, whereas negative one corresponds to fermions). How is the $N$-particle state have any relation with this permutation $P$, and what does it mean to have a permutation of a sequence, as in the case of $P$, which subsequently gives rise to the aforementioned representations of determinants and permanents?

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices?

Comment: I have just read the section, are you telling me that 'P' is some sort of inversion? Additionally, how does that fit in with the N-particle state?(could it be to do with creation and annihilation operators?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, $P$ is just a permutation of your indexing set $\{1, 2, ... N\}$. The whole permutations gig is to deal with the symmetrisation (resp. antisymmetrisation) for bosons (resp. fermions) of the multiparticle wavefunction, which should be familiar from quantum mechanics.

Comment: Yes, but in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation. It says that the index is an inversion of the permutation.

Comment: @Matrix001 could you clarify if you have previously met determinants in a linear algebra course of some kind? How would you prefer to define determinants?

Comment: I self-taught myself linear algebra, and like to define determinants via the Levi-Civita symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $N=3$ should make the meaning clear:$$\begin{align}\det A&=A_{11}A_{22}A_{33}-A_{11}A_{23}A_{32}+A_{12}A_{23}A_{31}-A_{12}A_{21}A_{33}+A_{13}A_{21}A_{32}-A_{13}A_{22}A_{31},\\\operatorname{perm} A&=A_{11}A_{22}A_{33}+A_{11}A_{23}A_{32}+A_{12}A_{23}A_{31}+A_{12}A_{21}A_{33}+A_{13}A_{21}A_{32}+A_{13}A_{22}A_{31}.\end{align}$$Note that $A_{12}A_{23}A_{31}$ ($A_{12}A_{21}A_{33}$) has a $+$ ($-$) sign in $\det A$ because $231$ ($213$) is an [even (odd) permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of $123$.